# About the value of $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\frac{(n-k)^n}{n!}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Is

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\frac{(n-k)^n}{n!} = 1$$

a common identity?

After extensive googling, I am unable to find anything on it specifically.

It came up as part of an answer to a previous binomial question of mine: [Binomial proof of $n! = n^r - n(n - 1)^r + \frac{n(n-1)}{2!}\left(n -2 \right)^r - \dots$ when $r = n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4707816/binomial-proof-of-n-nr-nn-1r-fracnn-12-leftn-2-rightr). I follow the entire argument of the accepted answer, but I don't see why $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\frac{(n-k)^n}{n!} = 1$. I'd prefer clarification within the context of the linked question, but combinatorial proofs are nice too.

Also, based on equating coefficients, the answer in the linked question implies that $$ \left(1 + \frac{x}{2!} + \frac{x^2}{3!} + \cdots \right)^n = 1$$

as well. I'm unfamiliar with this identity too, although it sort of looks like a Taylor series for...$1$??

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sum of alternating binomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2779348/sum-of-alternating-binomial) There are [many duplicates](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5En%20%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D(-1)%5Ekk%5En%24&p=1).

Comment: It's easy to see that $$ \left(1 + \frac{x}{2!} + \frac{x^2}{3!} + \cdots \right)^n = \left( \frac{e^x-1}{x} \right)^n$$ which is not $1$.

Comment: @awkward If you check out the link, the answerer ends up concluding that the coefficient of $x^n$ is both $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\frac{(n-k)^n}{n!} = 1$ *and* $\left(1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\cdots\right)^n \neq 1$. How does one make sense of that?

Comment: @AnneBauval Not really. My question is about an identity that contains the alternating binomial coefficients, but not exactly that identity itself. Moreover, I am interested in the specific argument I linked.

Comment: The claim in the linked-to solution is not that $ \left(1 + \frac{x}{2!} + \frac{x^2}{3!} + \cdots \right)^n = 1$ but that the coefficient of $x^n$ when the expression is expanded is $1$.

Comment: @akward "To finish up, we can go back to our original expression which was $\cdots =x^n\left(1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\cdots\right)^n$." I may be missing something obvious, but if we have $x^n \times \left(1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\cdots\right)^n$, how is $\left(1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\cdots\right)^n$ not its coefficient and thus equal to any other coefficient previously derived for it?

Comment: @awkward (Sorry, mistagged you in previous reply).

Comment: The duplicate I selected (among many others to which I linked) gives several proofs of the identity you are asking for. With a very small effort, you will realize that it actually *is exactly* "that identity itself".

Answer (score 3):

Reindexing your sum by replacing $k$ with $n-k$, we may observe that it is a special case of a Stirling number of the second kind, which is defined as$$
{n \brace j} = \frac{1}{j!} \sum_{k=0}^j (-1)^{j-k} \binom{j}{k}k^n.
$$
This is the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ labelled objects into $j$ nonempty, unlabelled subsets.  Your sum is ${n \brace n}$ which equals $1$.

Comment: Very slick! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Shift the index $\displaystyle \sum_{k=a}^{b}f(k) = \sum_{k=a}^{b}f(a+b-k)$ and recall $\displaystyle \binom {n}{k} = \binom {n}{n-k}$:

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\frac{(n-k)^n}{n!} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{n-k}(-1)^{n-k}\frac{k^n}{n!} = \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}{k^n}$

By [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081134/how-to-compute-sumn-k-0-1k-binomnkkn?) this is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\cdot (-1)^n n! = 1.$

I believe this is called [Tepper's identity](https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7390/8/2/243).